# Classifying Space of a Category Contractible

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, classifying-spaces

My question refers to a statement in Laures' and Szymik's "Grundkurs Topologie" (page 233). Sorry, there exist only a German version. Here the relevant excerpt:

[image]

My question is why a category having a initial (or a final) object has a ***contractible*** classifying space?

Previously the author just shows that equivalent categories induce homotopy equivalent classifying spaces via

$$BC\times \Delta^1 \to BD$$.

Does this observation provide an answer of my question? Why?

Here the construction of classifying space with which the author works:, namely as a nerve of the functor $B:Cat \to \Delta^{op}-Sets, C \mapsto Mor(-,C)$:

[image]

Comment: The nerve of such a category will be a cone.